# How to add instances in ontology from CSV file

Tags: ontology

I tried to add instances in ontology using WebProtege. But the problem is that data is not assigned as data/object property instead it is in the 'type' the heading under the 'Description'. Is there any other quick way to add indvisuals from CSV file.

Comment: I never used jena before kindly eleborate the steps. I tried apache-jena-fuseki but i enconter the error 503

Comment: I have read the ontology into model. Please share the script to convert the CSV file to Ontology acceptable form.

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Using Jena to read the ontology into Model **X**
2. Write small java code that will read each row of CSV file and convert it according the ontology vocabulary in the form  of RDF statement.
3. RDF Statements can then be stored into the same Model **X**.
   So at the end you will have both your ontology and data instances in the same model **X**.  Then print your model **X** into some file with extension of saved file as "RDF/XML".

Answer (score 0):

If using the Protégé Ontology editor environment you can use the plugin called "Cellfie" A Protégé Desktop plugin for mapping spreadsheets to OWL ontologies. The plugin is available in the menu item "Tools > Create axioms from Excel workbook..."